# How to find whether the k nearest neighbors of an instance belongs to same class or not

Tags: data-mining, matlab, k-nearest-neighbour

I am working on imbalanced datasets which have two classes: majority and minority class. Here I want to find whether the minority class examples are majority class. How  can I do that? I have implemented a code which finds k nearest neighbours for the minority class.
This is my code:

```
A=[1 2 1;3 4 1;5 6 1;];
 B=[1 2 2;3 14 2;15 16 2;17 18 2;1 2 1;3 4 1;5 6 1;];
%A=A1;B=B1;
[row,col]=size(A);
[row1,col1]=size(B);

dist=zeros(row,row1);
neararray = zeros(row,row1);
neararray1 = zeros(row,k);
k=5;

for i=1
  for j=1:row1
        dists(i,j)=sqrt(sum((A(1,1)-B(j,:)).^2));%for each element
  end

  [y,index]=sort(dist(1,:));
  neararray(i,:)=index';
  for k=1:5
  neararray1(i,k)=neararray(i,k);
  end
end



 Input:

    A is:
    feature1,feature2,class
         1     2     1
         3     4     1
         5     6     1
    B is:
    feature1,feature2,class
         1     2     2
         3    14     2
        15    16     2
        17    18     2
         1     2     1
         3     4     1
         5     6     1
```

My doubt is this approach correct? For example `A(1,1)` I will get nearest neighbours as: `1,5,6,7,2

But How can I say that it `A(1,1)` belongs to which class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm):

> [...] an object is classified by a majority vote of its neighbors, with the object being assigned to the class most common amongst its k nearest neighbors (k is a positive integer, typically small). If k = 1, then the object is simply assigned to the class of that single nearest neighbor.

So just check which class occurs most frequently in the list of neighbors. Note that the class prediction will be the same for all of your inputs if you choose k too high. I'm not sure why your output contains 7 values though, if $k=5$, you should get 5 nearest neighbors so you might have made a small mistake there.

Comment: Here the 7 values are the nearest neighbors from the whole training set

Comment: here by output can i say it belongs to same class as indexes 5,6,7 are the same class

Comment: That is correct, feel free to close the topic if that answers all your questions.